# Как сделать дисторшен эффект у картинки, js

Tags: javascript, css, изображения, обработка-изображений

Как можно сделать такой эффект при помощи js? Какой библиотекой?
Было бы супер, если можно ещё и анимировать это.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите - может что-то из этого устроит с некоторыми изменениями (например рябь на воде при максимальных настройках похожа) - https://codemyui.com/tag/distortion-effect/

Comment: Что-то похожее есть и в SVG и в WebGL. Причём почти нативное.

Comment: @UModeL почти нативное и webgl как-то не складывается :D

Comment: @МихаилКамахин: да, понимаю, что не так выразился. Имелось в виду количество кода.

Comment: @UModeL а найти сможете?

Comment: да, это 1-2 строчки в шейдере

Answer (score 7):

Вот слайдер с похожим эффектом, тут используется webgl

Автор: [`ashthornton`](https://codepen.io/ashthornton/pen/KRQbMO)

От себя добавил переключение слайдера вверх-вниз на клавиатуре

```js
const displacementSlider = function (opts) {
  let vertex = `
        varying vec2 vUv;
        void main() {
          vUv = uv;
          gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        }
    `;

  let fragment = `
        
        varying vec2 vUv;

        uniform sampler2D currentImage;
        uniform sampler2D nextImage;

        uniform float dispFactor;

        void main() {

            vec2 uv = vUv;
            vec4 _currentImage;
            vec4 _nextImage;
            float intensity = 0.3;

            vec4 orig1 = texture2D(currentImage, uv);
            vec4 orig2 = texture2D(nextImage, uv);
            
            _currentImage = texture2D(currentImage, vec2(uv.x, uv.y + dispFactor * (orig2 * intensity)));

            _nextImage = texture2D(nextImage, vec2(uv.x, uv.y + (1.0 - dispFactor) * (orig1 * intensity)));

            vec4 finalTexture = mix(_currentImage, _nextImage, dispFactor);

            gl_FragColor = finalTexture;

        }
    `;

  let images = opts.images,
    image,
    sliderImages = [];
  let canvasWidth = images[0].clientWidth;
  let canvasHeight = images[0].clientHeight;
  let parent = opts.parent;
  let renderWidth = Math.max(
    document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    window.innerWidth || 0
  );
  let renderHeight = Math.max(
    document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    window.innerHeight || 0
  );

  let renderW, renderH;

  if (renderWidth > canvasWidth) {
    renderW = renderWidth;
  } else {
    renderW = canvasWidth;
  }

  renderH = canvasHeight;

  let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: false,
  });

  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setClearColor(0x23272a, 1.0);
  renderer.setSize(renderW, renderH);
  parent.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

  images.forEach((img) => {
    image = loader.load(img.getAttribute("src") + "?v=" + Date.now());
    image.magFilter = image.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    image.anisotropy = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();
    sliderImages.push(image);
  });

  let scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x23272a);
  let camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    renderWidth / -2,
    renderWidth / 2,
    renderHeight / 2,
    renderHeight / -2,
    1,
    1000
  );

  camera.position.z = 1;

  let mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      dispFactor: {
        type: "f",
        value: 0.0,
      },
      currentImage: {
        type: "t",
        value: sliderImages[0],
      },
      nextImage: {
        type: "t",
        value: sliderImages[1],
      },
    },
    vertexShader: vertex,
    fragmentShader: fragment,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 1.0,
  });

  let geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(
    parent.offsetWidth,
    parent.offsetHeight,
    1
  );
  let object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
  object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  scene.add(object);

  let addEvents = function () {
    function animationOneElem(event) {
      if (!isAnimating) {
        isAnimating = true;

        document
          .getElementById("pagination")
          .querySelectorAll(".active")[0].className = "";
        this.className = "active";

        let slideId = parseInt(this.dataset.slide, 10);

        mat.uniforms.nextImage.value = sliderImages[slideId];
        mat.uniforms.nextImage.needsUpdate = true;

        TweenLite.to(mat.uniforms.dispFactor, 1, {
          value: 1,
          ease: "Expo.easeInOut",
          onComplete: function () {
            mat.uniforms.currentImage.value = sliderImages[slideId];
            mat.uniforms.currentImage.needsUpdate = true;
            mat.uniforms.dispFactor.value = 0.0;
            isAnimating = false;
          },
        });

        let slideTitleEl = document.getElementById("slide-title");
        let slideStatusEl = document.getElementById("slide-status");
        let nextSlideTitle = document.querySelectorAll(
          `[data-slide-title="${slideId}"]`
        )[0].innerHTML;
        let nextSlideStatus = document.querySelectorAll(
          `[data-slide-status="${slideId}"]`
        )[0].innerHTML;

        TweenLite.fromTo(
          slideTitleEl,
          0.5,
          {
            autoAlpha: 1,
            filter: "blur(0px)",
            y: 0,
          },
          {
            autoAlpha: 0,
            filter: "blur(10px)",
            y: 20,
            ease: "Expo.easeIn",
            onComplete: function () {
              slideTitleEl.innerHTML = nextSlideTitle;

              TweenLite.to(slideTitleEl, 0.5, {
                autoAlpha: 1,
                filter: "blur(0px)",
                y: 0,
              });
            },
          }
        );

        TweenLite.fromTo(
          slideStatusEl,
          0.5,
          {
            autoAlpha: 1,
            filter: "blur(0px)",
            y: 0,
          },
          {
            autoAlpha: 0,
            filter: "blur(10px)",
            y: 20,
            ease: "Expo.easeIn",
            onComplete: function () {
              slideStatusEl.innerHTML = nextSlideStatus;

              TweenLite.to(slideStatusEl, 0.5, {
                autoAlpha: 1,
                filter: "blur(0px)",
                y: 0,
                delay: 0.1,
              });
            },
          }
        );
      }
    }

    const paginationDOM = document.getElementById("pagination");
    const btns = Array.from(paginationDOM.querySelectorAll("button"));

    let isAnimating = false;

    btns.forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener("click", animationOneElem);
    });

    window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      const idx = [...btns].findIndex(item => item.classList[0] === 'active');
      if ((e.key === 'ArrowUp' || e.code === "ArrowUp") && idx !== 0) { // вверх
        const buttonActive = btns[idx - 1];
        animationOneElem.bind(buttonActive, e)();
      } else if ((e.key === 'ArrowDown' || e.code === "ArrowDown") && idx !== btns.length - 1) {
        const buttonActive = btns[idx + 1];
        animationOneElem.bind(buttonActive, e)();
      }
    });
  };

  addEvents();

  window.addEventListener("resize", function (e) {
    renderer.setSize(renderW, renderH);
  });

  let animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };
  animate();
};

imagesLoaded(document.querySelectorAll("img"), () => {
  document.body.classList.remove("loading");

  const el = document.getElementById("slider");
  const imgs = Array.from(el.querySelectorAll("img"));
  new displacementSlider({
    parent: el,
    images: imgs,
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/euz1eqv.css");
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}
a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}
hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}
mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}
code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
q {
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}
small {
  font-size: 80%;
}
sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}
img {
  border: 0;
}
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}
legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}
button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}
button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
::selection {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
html {
  background: #fff;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
body {
  background-color: #23272a;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
header {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123024/menutexture.png);
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: auto 200px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
header .inner {
  max-width: 1060px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
header .logo {
  display: block;
  width: 76px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
header .logo img {
  width: 45px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
header nav {
  display: none;
}
header nav a {
  font-family: "Arial", serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #8c8c8e;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 18px;
}
header nav a.active,
header nav a:hover {
  color: white;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  header nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
header .burger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
header .burger:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 0 0 white, 0 6px 0 0 white;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  header .burger {
    display: none;
  }
}
header .donate-link {
  width: 72px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 27px;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#slider canvas {
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
#slider img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.slider-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1060px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 5;
}
#slider-content {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#slider-content h2 {
  font-family: "acta-display", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0 60px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #slider-content h2 {
    font-size: 110px;
    line-height: 100px;
  }
}
#slider-content span {
  display: none;
}
#slider-content .meta {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #88888a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #slider-content .meta {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
#slider-content .meta:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: -55px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #393d40;
}
#slider-content #slide-status {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: "acta-display", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #slider-content #slide-status {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
}
#pagination {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 6;
}
#pagination button {
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.2;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
}
#pagination button:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#pagination button.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
#pagination button.active:before {
  width: 300%;
  height: 300%;
  opacity: 1;
}
#pagination button:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, width 0.4s ease-in-out,
    height 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
/* Page Loader */
.loading:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.loading:after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100000;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: -30px 0 0 -30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background: white;
  animation: loaderAnim 0.7s linear infinite alternate forwards;
}
@keyframes loaderAnim {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/4.1.4/imagesloaded.pkgd.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.4/TweenMax.min.js'></script>

<body class="loading">

  <main>
    <div id="slider">

      <div class="slider-inner">
        <div id="slider-content">
          <div class="meta">Species</div>
          <h2 id="slide-title">Amur <br>Leopard</h2>
          <span data-slide-title="0">Amur <br>Leopard</span>
          <span data-slide-title="1">Asiatic <br>Lion</span>
          <span data-slide-title="2">Siberian <br>Tiger</span>
          <span data-slide-title="3">Brown <br>Bear</span>
          <div class="meta">Status</div>
          <div id="slide-status">Critically Endangered</div>
          <span data-slide-status="0">Critically Endangered</span>
          <span data-slide-status="1">Endangered</span>
          <span data-slide-status="2">Endangered</span>
          <span data-slide-status="3">Least Concern</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123024/leopard2.jpg" />
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123024/lion2.jpg" />
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123024/tiger2.jpg" />
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123024/bear2.jpg" />

      <div id="pagination">
        <button class="active" data-slide="0"></button>
        <button data-slide="1"></button>
        <button data-slide="2"></button>
        <button data-slide="3"></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7):

Если без дополнительного выпендрёжа то это просто uv коордианата по y сложена с синусом от uv координаты по x

```js
RGBA(`
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution;
    uv.y += sin(uv.x*100.0)*.2;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex[0], uv);
`, {
   textures: [ `https://picsum.photos/600`]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/strangerintheq/rgba/0.0.4/rgba.js"></script>
```

Comment: можно еще отяготить поворотом

Comment: Это конечно супер-круто, но я так понимаю это твоя библиотека, от которой очень сложно будет сделать что-то другое шагом в сторону. Это совсем не очень.
Неужели на ваниле такого не написать?

Comment: @VostokSisters там находится минимальный код, который делает рутинную операцию, при использовании другой графической библиотеки будет дугой код для рисования одного прямоулогьника, суть ответа именно в том, какое преобразовпние необходимо применить во фрагментном шейдере

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Мне понравилось. Очень круто.

Answer (score 5):

### SVG Filters

Анимация искажения при наведении курсора.

Можно хорошо поиграться, затачивая фильтры, вернее их атрибуты `baseFrequency`,`scale` под желаемый эффект

```html
<style>
.container {
width:60%;
height:60%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"   viewBox="0 0 500 300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="myFilter" >
      <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.0001" numOctaves="1" result="turbulence" >
     <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" dur="18s" values="0.0001;0.02;0.0001;0.02;0.0001" begin="img1.mouseover" end="img1.mouseout" />
      </feTurbulence>
     <feDisplacementMap xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G" scale="25" in="SourceGraphic" in2="turbulence" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHGO8.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#myFilter)" /> 
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Привет снова ушел в подполье ?

Comment: @Leks Да не, просто самому старая аватарка надоела.

Comment: хорошо а то я уже подумал...